# Необходимо вытащить строку из коллекции

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, поиск, коллекции

Есть коллекция строк, необходимо её прогнать через регулярные выражения( с целью разбиения на слова, предложения, знаки препинания) с помощью `Pattern`, `Matcher` (вообщем нужно это для того что бы сделать парсер).
Но как я понял matcher требует строку, а не коллекцию.

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пройтись по всем объектам в коллекции можно циклом `foreach`

```
Collection<String> collection = new Collection<>();
collection.add("Это");
collection.add("очень");
collection.add("просто!");
for (String item : collection) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Выведет:

```
Это
очень
просто!
```

Comment: Большое спасибо вам!
Ещё один вопрос по этой же теме, я все сделал, а как мне теперь строку прогнать через регулярное выражение?(через pattern, matcher)
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text)
Вот вместо text, я так понимаю должна быть строка, исходя из моей коллекции, что мне туда необходимо вставить? Если я вставляю коллекцию, он ругается, требует строку.

Comment: Внутри цикла каждый элемент коллекции представлен переменной `item` Вот её и передавайте в методы, требующие строку в качестве аргумента.